# Browser cache management during local development

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, caching, maps

While testing in development, how can you disable cache for all your local scripts/styles, and keep the cache working for all the external scripts/styles? Preferably firefox

Basically when making changes to css, js, or sprite files on my site I'm developing, I need to reload them frequently, but the external hosted scripts/images/styles like google maps, jquery etc will make the wait time up to 5-10 seconds every time (this is mainly due to the fact that I am located in a Country with poor internet access)

Comment: Is your development environment running locally?

Comment: @Yes, all the scripts are being loaded directly from our office server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set appropriate [HTTP caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13) directives (expecially [*ETag*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.19), [*Cache-Control*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9) and [*Expires*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21)) for your local site.

For Apache you can use [`Header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) to unset *ETag*, and set *Cache-Control* and *Expires* with appropriate values:

```
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control no-store, max-age=0
Header set Expires 0
```